# Laravel 5.1 AJAX - Returning 405 GET Method Not Allowed even when I am sending a POST request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, heroku, laravel-5.1

My Laravel POST route returns 405 GET Method not allowed when I am sending a POST request through AJAX. However the problem is that it works in `localhost` but not working in Heroku `production server`. My AJAX POST request gets sent as GET request to the route. Below i have attached a screenshot and my AJAX code.

```
$.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token
            }
        })
```

My route is configured as:

```
Route::post('/adminpanel/projects/delete/', 'AdminPanelController@deleteData');
```

[image]

Comment: Try removing that `/adminpanel/projects/delete` `<----- last slash` I'm not sure but that worked for me

Comment: Damn man.. Thanks A Lot.. Its working.. Any idea why it worked ?? Please post your comment as answer I will upvote it...

Comment: I don't know the reason why its creating an issue within server but solved it two days ago only. I've searched a lot for this but couldn't find the solution and finally solved at own

Comment: Hmm.. I think its Heroku issue because in localhost its working without any probs..

Comment: Might be but I can't answer for the reason behind it

Comment: Hmm ... :) ..............

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update your action `url` from

```
/adminpanel/projects/delete/
```

into

```
/adminpanel/projects/delete
                        //^^ Removed that slash
```

Remove that slash and it'll work for you.

Comment: Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a resource in Laravel, then check the routes list by command :

```
php artisan route:list
```

See, If the POST request you are trying to send is allowed in the routes or not. 405 error is generally because we forgot to mention the request in the routes.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked after I put the route out of the localization route group. I am using [laravel-localization](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization).